# Unsure how to make an Azure AD app registration that can have its own onedrive folder

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am working on a project that needs to have a Onedrive folder that it owns where it can store and edit certain files. This folder also needs to be accessible through Onedrive to certain users in my organization.
I have created an App Registration in Azure AD, but can't figure out what permissions and configuration I need to achieve this. I know I can give it access to authenticate to a user and edit/create files on their behalf, but I don't want the folder/files to be associated with any particular user in the organization. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean that give the permissions to access the Onedrive folder without a signed-in user? If so,  try to add the [application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/permissions_reference?view=odsp-graph-online#application-permissions).

Answer (score 0):

You might try creating and managing items using [application credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). Also take a look to [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permission?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/shared?view=graph-rest-1.0) for more information about making it accesible to others.

Answer (score 0):

Are the files you're looking to store files that are visible to users or that are "data files" for your app?  We don't currently recommend building apps that only store their own proprietary files rather than operating on visible user data. (It's a little more nuanced situation when you look at lists rather than libraries of files).

In general files that are expected to be shared among users without a single user owning them would be placed in a SharePoint site.  You can then manage the permissions of the site to give access to the users that need the files.  OneDrive for Business is specifically intended for files owned by an individual user.

At the moment we don't have provisioning APIs available through Microsoft Graph to create a site programmatically today, but you can look at the PnP Provisioning Engine for how to automate the process with legacy APIs, or if you really just need a single site you can create the site manually and then refer to it from your application.

The Drive API is the same whether you're accessing a OneDrive for Business or SharePoint site.